# \logo command problem with Latex beamer theme "Marburg"

Tags: beamer

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

This is the code, I have used Warsaw theme but for the theme "Marburg" the logo command is not working...How the logo in the left can be placed in the sidebar same position as the picture???

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer} 
\mode<presentation>{}
%\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\graphicspath{ {/home/user} }
\usetheme{Warsaw} %Marburg %Goettingen
\usecolortheme{sidebartab}
\useinnertheme{rounded}



\logo{%
    \makebox[0.96\paperwidth]{%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{wbsu}%
    \hfill{}%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{test}\hspace{0.05\textwidth}%
}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{This is frame title}
\framesubtitle{sample slide for showing logo command}
    This is where something to be written.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead or redefining the `footline` template, you can simply add the logos using `\addtobeamertemplate`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer} 

\usetheme{Marburg}
\usecolortheme{sidebartab}
\useinnertheme{rounded}

\addtobeamertemplate{footline}{}{%
\makebox[\paperwidth]{%
    \hspace{0.04\textwidth}\raisebox{2ex}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}}%
    \hfill{}%
    \raisebox{2ex}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}}\hspace{0.04\textwidth}%
}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{This is the frame title}
\framesubtitle{Sample slide for showing the logo}
Some test text.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

[image]

You need to redefine the `footline` template for the `Marburg` theme as this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer} 
\mode<presentation>{}
%\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{graphicx,lmodern}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\graphicspath{ {/home/user} }
\usetheme{Marburg}%{Warsaw}%Goettingen
\usecolortheme{sidebartab}
\useinnertheme{rounded}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
  {%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
      \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
      \else%
        \hfill%
      \fi%
      \ifdim\beamer@sidebarwidth>0pt%  
        \usebeamercolor[bg]{logo}%
        \hfill\hbox to \beamer@sidebarwidth{\hss\vbox to
          \beamer@headheight{\vss\hbox{\color{fg}\insertlogo}\vss}\hss}%
      \else%
        \vrule width0pt height \beamer@headheight%  
      \fi%
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  }
\logo{%
    \raisebox{1.5cm}{\includegraphics[width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-A}}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{This is frame title}
\framesubtitle{sample slide for showing logo command}
    This is where something to be written.
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{This is frame title 2}
\framesubtitle{sample slide for showing logo command}
    This is where something to be written.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And the other image?! (I also tried to do it this way ;).)

Comment: @cfr _"How the logo in the left can be placed in the sidebar same position as the picture???"_  This is the question, no body will use two logos in the footline.

Comment: The definition of the `\logo` includes 2 images. And the slide shows 2 images. Any time you say 'nobody will...' you are borrowing trouble ;).